# Using marker interfaces in android studio / IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to manage relatively large projects in Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA. I want to use a marker interface to indicate a class that is unfinished in some way.

```
public interface ToDo {
}
```

The trouble is that when I click the "has implementations" icon, I get a list of all subclasses of classes that include the words `implements ToDo`, including anonymous ones (as I should). Is it possible to do a search so that I only get a list of classes where the words `implements ToDo` actually appear? If not, is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: "Find in path" isn't the option?

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji You're right. CTRL + SHIFT + F then type "implements ToDo". Easy. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Find in path"` on the project folder will do the work.

[image: Find in path]

[image: text to search]

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative way for intellij & Android Studio**

1. From the app menu, Edit > Find > Find in Path (quick tip the keyboard shortcut will be listed next to the menu option)
2. type in " implements ToDo" in `text to find`
3. For Scope, Select Custom "Project Files" (this will help you avoid some generated classes coming up in your search results)
4. For File name filter, check the checkbox for "File masks" and type in "*.java" in the textbox next to it.
5. Click "find".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works and it is what I needed. (+1).

Comment: @PaulBoddington sweet!,  happy to help..feel free to accept the answer...and welcome to android!!!!!